# spark streaming, how to track processed source files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

How does the spark streaming keeps the track of files which have been processed?

Question 1: Let's take a scenario, spark has processed today’s files(a.csv, b.csv, c.csv), and after 3 days new file(d.csv) has arrived, how does spark know it has to process the only d.csv? what is the underlying mechanism followed here?

Question 2: As a user, I want to know whether the files have been really processed, how can I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does the spark streaming keeps the track of files which have been
> processed?

The responsible class for this is [FileStreamSource](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSource.scala). Here you will find answers for the next 2 questions.

> how does spark know it has to process the only d.csv? what is the
> underlying mechanism followed here?

A `CompactibleFileStreamLog` is used to maintain a mapping of seen files based on timestamp when it was last modified. Based on these entries an ever-increasing offset is created (ref. `FileStreamSourceOffset`). This offset is checkpointed across runs much like other streaming sources like Kafka.

> whether the files have been really processed, how can I check?

From the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSource.scala#L164) I can see that you can check this via DEBUG logs,

```
 batchFiles.foreach { file =>
  seenFiles.add(file._1, file._2)
  logDebug(s"New file: $file")
}
```

Another place you may check is the checkpoint data but since it contains serialized offset info I doubt you will get any details from there.